# How to return string in JavaScript without Typing string

Tags: javascript

I have been writing JavaScript for long time but I just met this piece of code which renders to "mk break fix", how this can work and what if I want it to render another string?

Please look this code:

```
([].map+0)[9]+([].keys+0)[9]+
(top+0)[7]+(typeof!1)[0]+(!0+'')[1]+
(!1+'')[4]+(-{}+'')[1]+([].keys+0)[9]+
(top+0)[7]+(''.fixed+0).slice(9,12)
```

So how does it happen to even return a text here?

Comment: puzzle code is really not very useful to anybody.

Comment: just how it works out of curiosity?

Comment: Break it up into sections and plug it into the console and you will see what it is doing

Comment: @DanielL great now more clear, a function to function text string then pick the letter from the string by index